# Como puedo agregar elementos a una lista de objectos y mostralo en una vista sin sustituir el anterior atraves de un formulario?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Models/Person.cs

```
public class PersonController : Controller {

    List<Person> personasList = new List<Person> () { };
    public IActionResult Index () {

        return View ();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index (Person persona) {


        personasList.Add (persona);

        return View(personasList);

    }
}
```

Controllers/PersonController.cs

```
public class PersonController : Controller {

    List<Person> personasList = new List<Person> () { };
    public IActionResult Index () {

        return View ();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index (Person persona) {


        personasList.Add (persona);

        return View(personasList);

    }
}
```

Views/Person/Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<MyMVC.Models.Person>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <form method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Nombre:")
        @Html.TextBox("firstName", null, new { @class = "form-control" }) 
      </div>

       <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Apellido:")
        @Html.TextBox("lastName", null, new { @class = "form-control" }) 
      </div>

       <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Edad:")
        @Html.TextBox("Age", null, new { @class = "form-control" }) 
      </div>

       <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Email:")
        @Html.TextBox("Email", null, new { @class = "form-control" }) 
      </div>
    <hr/>
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<table class="table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.firstName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.lastName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Age)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>

 <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.firstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)
        </td>
           <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>

    </tr>   
  }
```

Comment: Si, soy un pricipiante en esto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay tres opciones que se me ocurren.
La primera que yo te recomendaría es hacerlo desde el lado del cliente, en este caso la vista que tienes con alguna librería de javascritp, como por ejemplo AngularJS o jQuery, así te evitas la llamada al servidor.

Pueder ver como hacerlo con angular utilizando ng-repeat aquí
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

La segunda, que no te recomiendo del todo, es que tu lista de "Person" sea estática, eso evitará que se borre el contenido.
Pero deberías documentarte un poco sobre el uso de variables estáticas.

Para esto, solo agregas en tu controlador:

```
static List<Person> personasList = new List<Person> () { };
```

Una tercer forma es utilizando el TempData para mantener la información de la lista actual.

En el controller

```
personasList = TempData["miLista"];
```

Y en el view, lo inverso

```
TempData["miLista"] = personasList;
```

Espero esto te pueda ayudar.

Comment: Gracias. Me funcionó con la lista estática. Seguiré probando con TempData.

Comment: Solo ten cuidado con las variables estáticas, porque no resetean su valor hasta que se lo asignes... pordrías por ejemplo agregar en tu controlador una condición if(nombre==""){personasList = new List<Person>()} así, la primera vez que llames a la vista... sin ningún parametro, te limpiará la lista

Comment: Si está respuesta solucionó tu pregunta, debés marcarla como aceptada. Saludos.